# How to selectively remove a particular value from a column which contains more than one value each separated by a comma, using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, plsql

for example, consider a table like below (`table name=accounts)`

```
account        owner_ids
PA account     sa123,rt458,hf678,de348f
RA account     gg678n,fk980,rt458,hf678
```

Here, I want to remove `owner_ids "rt458" and "hf678"` from the entire table and after removing the commas should be perfect (I mean after removing also the remaining owner_ids should be separated by comma as before and there should not be any unnecessary comma in the column)

Any kind of help is appreciated, Help me out guys

Comment: Helping you out here means pointing out that your CSV data is unnormalized, and therefore hard to work with.  You should get owner id onto a separate row.

Comment: @vega et al.  -  I see you marked this as a duplicate of another question. What you did here is an abuse; the question you linked to is different. You may have your own opinion on how bad the OP's data model is (I agree with that opinion), but that doesn't give you the right to abuse the system. Shame on you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm) function twice:

```
update accounts 
set owner_ids = REPLACE(REPLACE(owner_ids,
             ',rt458' ),',hf678');
```

> REPLACE returns char with every occurrence of search_string replaced with replacement_string.

Or you can use [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/functions115.htm#SQLRF06302) to replace/remove those values by regex:

```
update accounts 
set owner_ids = REGEXP_REPLACE(owner_ids,
             '(\,rt458||\,hf678)', '');
```

> REGEXP_REPLACE extends the functionality of the REPLACE function by letting you search a string for a regular expression pattern.

To support case where rt458 is the first entry in the CSV list (As @TimBiegeleisen commented) you will have to allow no comma as:

```
update accounts 
set owner_ids = REGEXP_REPLACE(owner_ids,
             '(\,{0,1}rt458||\,{0,1}hf678)', '');
```

Using replace you will need to double calls:

```
update accounts 
set owner_ids = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(owner_ids,
             ',rt458' ),',hf678', 'rt458,', 'hf678,');
```

Also you can see [other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443731/how-to-remove-specific-value-from-comma-separated-string-in-oracle) to remove value from comma separated string

Comment: What about the case where `rt458` is the first entry in the CSV list?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for commenting, I updated my answer

Comment: What about the case where there is another token, `rt4586`, which mustn't be removed? You will just remove `rt458` from it, leaving the `6`. The problem can be solved with REPLACE, but the solution must be written with much more care than you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE accounts
SET owner_ids = TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM
    REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT(',', owner_ids, ','), ',rt458,', ''), ',hf678,', '')
);
```

First prepend and append the field with a comma `CONCAT(',', owner_ids, ',')` to make it uniform.

Then, remove `,rt458,` and `,hf678,` from it.

Later remove commas from both at the start and end which we added to make the structure uniform.

This will maintain single commas between the values.

> Please note, you should prefer normalizing `owner_ids` so that such updates are easy to handle.

Comment: What if one of the tokens is `rt4586`? Your solution will remove `rt458`, leaving the `6` behind (when in fact that token shouldn't be touched in the first place).

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. Updated my answer. Thank you for pointing it out.